# Can we dismiss the phone activity view programatically in iOS? If yes, how do we dismiss it?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to dismiss the activity view which gets opened on click of a telephone number programmatically in iOS. Is it possible to dismiss it?

I have a use case in my application where on click of the telephone number the activity view should be displayed. If the device is kept idle for some time the account gets logged off and goes to the login screen. I would like to dismiss this activity view before the view gets navigated to the login screen.

[image]

Comment: I suspect not. You should, however, be able to prevent it from being displayed in the first place. As I recall the system calls a method asking to open a URL and you have a chance to tell it not to. (It's been quite a while since I've looked at that part of iOS, so my memory is quite vague.)

Comment: The method a method of UITextViewDelegate, `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:interaction:`. If the user clicks a phone number link in a text view, the OS will call that method in your text view's delegate. Simply return `false` to tell the system not to open the link. That will prevent the `call <number>` activity view from being displayed in the first place.

Comment: @DuncanC I have a use case in my application where on click of the telephone number this activity view should be displayed and if the device is kept idle for some time the account gets logged off and goes to login screen. I would like to dismiss this activity view before the view gets navigated to login screen.